# Incremental file copy on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, log-files

Is there an effecient way to mirror text log files between two Windows servers?

I'd like to ship the logs off a production server to another server for near real-time analysis.

The log files are 1 file per day, 100MB per file, append only.

Comment: Are you sure you really want to copy the logs?  If these are standard Windows event logs, perhaps you could setup one of the tools that permit you to have Windows events forward to a remote syslog host?

Comment: They are text files. I'd like to do analysis on them while not affecting the production server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[DFS-R](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb540026%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is reasonably close to real-time, and does incremental shipping.

We use it to ship text-based log files to a remote site for analysis and processing. The files are typically only 2-3 minutes behind.

It will replicate anything, and if you access the data via its DFS Namespace rather than its local path, it has the advantage of routing to your lowest-cost server whilst maintaining the same directory path.

Answer (score 0):

For a simplistic solution you could also use `robocopy /MIR` for this and set it to run when you need it via scheduled tasks.  Not as robust as DFS-R, but not as complicated.